# alarm for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, productivity

Is there an alarm app for ubuntu 20.04?

Features:
1)In alarm we need to set the time at which it should ring.Not the remaining time from now.

2)(optional) should ring untill I stop atleast some reasonable ringing time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of GNOME shell extensions you can use for this.

`Reminder Alarm Clock`

[image]

Or this one `Alarm Clock` which also shows up the name of the upcoming alarm:

[image]

and lastly, there is

[image]

downloadable from the ubuntu software center.

Comment: Thanks.Reminder Alarm Clock worked for me.for Reminder alarm clock to play sound,we need to change the extension settings appropraitely.Mentioning for the sake of completeness ;)

Answer (score 5):

That is what, among other possible applications, the Gnome Clocks application does if you use the default Ubuntu version. If it is not installed, then you can install it with the command `sudo apt install gnome-clocks`.

Comment: but gnome-clocks somehow doesn't make any sound in ubuntu20.04.Just a popup appears

Comment: @CHANDRASEKHARHETHAHAVYA Gnome Clocks does create a single tick sound after the timer is finished.